# How to get project's implementation in gradle?

Tags: gradle, project

A `build.gradle` file represents an instance of `Project` in gradle. But `Project` is just an interface.
The question is: how to get `Project`'s implementation (kind of like *.java, *.class) that corresponds to the `build.gradle` script?

Comment: There's really no reason for downvoting this question. Much better would be to point out why it doesn't comply with the standards and what should be done to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`build.gradle` is not an equivalent of `Project`'s implementation. It's *executed* on a passed `Project` instance, this is not the same. To know the implementation class of `Project` run the script below:

```
println project.getClass()
```

You'll get `org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated` which points to [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/internal/project/DefaultProject.java) class. What is this `_Decorated` suffix? As pointed [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/internal/AbstractClassGenerator.java) and [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/internal/AsmBackedClassGenerator.java) it marks the class as preprocessed. The goal of this preprocessing is:

> Generates a subclass of the target class to mix-in some DSL behaviour.

Comment: the links are broken